# Why mpd server does not output any sound?

Tags: linux, audio

I am trying to run [MPD](http://www.musicpd.org/) server on Ubuntu 12.04.3. All worked with Ubuntu 11.10 and even with earlier 12.04. I am using Sonata as frontend and i get connected, playlists are available, i can choose a song, play it -- except getting audio out. Sound system is based on pulse-audio.

MPD has pretty good Wiki and [pulse-audio configuration](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/PulseAudio) is covered too. I have tried debug my problems, but still did not get working.

What i have? I have:

- mpd daemon working with started pulse-audio, in

  ```
  $ ps aux | grep -i mpd
  mpd      13770  3.9  5.4 144500 13636 ?        Ssl  Sep13 331:18 /usr/bin/mpd /etc/mpd.conf
  mpd      13778  1.4  1.0  88516  2532 ?        Sl   Sep13 119:21 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
  ```
- In /etc/mpd.conf i have

  ```
  audio_output {
          type            "pulse"
          name            "MPD PulseAudio Output"
          # sink      your-sink-name-here"
  }
  ```
- for sake in /etc/pulse/client.conf i enabled autospawn ( already default?):

  ```
  autospawn = yes
  ```
- in /var/log/mpd/mpd.log i see played songs
- under user "mpd" **i can play music with mplayer** and it works well with pulse-audio

I **can't** get

- list of sinks under usual user or mpd:

  ```
  $ pacmd list-sinks
  No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
  ```
- any sound from mpd-server

In syslog i see, that pulse can't connect to d-bus, like:

```
    Sep 19 20:43:23 musa pulseaudio[787]: [pulseaudio] module-always-sink.c: Unable to load module-null-sink
    Sep 19 20:43:54 musa pulseaudio[1098]: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
    Sep 19 20:43:54 musa pulseaudio[1098]: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

How to get mpd working again?

Comment: It looks like you need either to tell mpd which pulseaudio sink to use or setup pulseaudio to use the right sink by default. pulseaudio errored while trying to load module-null-sink, but even if it had succeeded this sink just silently throws audio data away, so that is not what you want. What is the output of `pacmd list-sinks`?

Comment: @wingedsubmariner: yes, this may be a problem, but a) output of `pacmd list-sinks` is in my posting and b) mplayer plays well under ordinary user and under mpd-user too. I see that there is a problem connecting to D-BUS.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem in Arch linux.  pulseaudio processs is running and Kodi can output sound to it, but mpd does not and I cannot get a list of sinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Archlinux, not Ubuntu but I had the same problem.  Apparently, the reason pacmd list-sinks didn't work is because apparently environment DISPLAY needs to be set ([forum discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=155649)).  After I set this for the user I could get list of sinks.  I reconfigured systemd mpd.service to start mpd as my user and set Environment="DISPLAY=:0".

Unfortunately this implies user has to be logged into an X session, and the system has xorg installed.  I think you can re-configure PulseAudio to run as a daemon for the entire system but with possible security issues ([aside from this blurb I don't know specifically what they are](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Configuration))

Comment: For me was solution to turn back to Alsa. But I hope your solution will help those who run mpd on desktop. For server I don't use X.